# How do I put a media player on my website?

Tags: html

I am making a streaming website for my third year project of a Computer Science degree. I was wondering how to put a media player on my website. The media player won't need to play anything and there will be a link to the media player from a selection of movies/ tv shows similar to Netflix.

Comment: please share more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio or video tag will not work in IE 8 version.

If you want browser support (IE > 8), use video or audio tag for playing video or audio file.

```
<video width="400"height="240" controls>
  <source src="filepath.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="filepath.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="filepath.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

For audio

```
<audio controls>  
  <source src="filepath.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: That doesn't look bad actually, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use html5 video or audio tag

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
 </video>
```